# SetWindowDisplayAffinity() not working with some particular windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm pretty new to Windows programming.

I've been assigned the task of hiding any specific window(s), given a `pid`, from being recorded using `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()`. With the help of DLL injection, it works as expected (as far as I've tested), but when I used it on Visual Studio itself, it did work, but that glowing frame around it persisted.

I Google'd and someone pointed out that it's using the extended window style `WS_EX_LAYERED`, and that I can look at its properties using `Spy++`. Here's what it looks like:

[image: spy++ screenshot]

I was afraid the function that calls `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()` from my injected DLL did it wrong somehow (the starter code given to me had a `do..while` loop calling `FindWindowEx()` which I felt, for some reason, didn't come by the window handle of the glowing frame). So, I wrote my own code to retrieve all current thread IDs, and call `EnumThreadWindows()` for each one of them, which consequently called my callback function, which then called `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()`.

The code worked as before, but didn't fix the issue. So, I've set an array which I used to store all window handles that were passed to `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()`, and with the help of `Spy++` and `MessageBox()` (my debugging techniques are archaic, I know), I made sure the main window handle AND the glowing frame handle both were indeed in there.

Here's an image for reference:

[image: glowing_frame_still_showing_after_setwda]

I doubted that `WS_EX_LAYERED` prevented `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()` from doing its job, but I'm still clueless.

**Edit**:

I've logged the last error in case `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()` did fail, for some reason. It turns out it did, and the error was `not enough memory resources are available to process this command` with error code `0x8`, and as I expected the error only showed on the 4 drop shadow border window handles (logged the handles and compared them to `Spy++`'s info).

**Edit**:

I've found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ce400f0-ebda-4b95-869c-85b5b93f972d/win32-setwindowdisplayaffinity?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues), I guess it sums everything up? Is there any hope left?

**Edit**:

I've currently setteled for this non-practical workaround:

```cpp
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: @Dai I do know the drop shadow has it's own ```hwnd```, this knowledge doesn't really fix my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723579/call-win32-api-in-flex-to-set-window-display-affinity

Comment: @HansPassant I did read that, my edit mentions a post where they say `SetWindowAffinity()` raises a misleading error when calling it on a window with the extended style `WS_EX_LAYERED`, and that it isn't currently supported.