# Setting Pyside6 windows in EXCLUDE FROM CAPTURE mode

Tags: python, qt, pywin32, pyside6

I'm trying to SetWindowDisplayAffinity in a PySide6 Window (QT6) but for some reason it's not working, already tried running as admin but nothing works.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout

import ctypes
from ctypes import windll

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()

    hwnd = widget.winId()

    widget.setWindowTitle("Hide Widget from Capture")
    
    # WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE - 0x00000011
    # WDA_NONE - 0x00000000

    windll.user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, 11)

    # Add a label to the widget
    label = QLabel("This widget it's suppose to be hidden from capture but is not")
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    widget.show()

    app.exec()
```

When screenshare/capture it's not suppose to show the window.

Comment: Post a debugging details such as the return value of ```SetWindowDisplayAffinity()``` and ```GetLastError()```. Anyway, you should use ```0x11``` for WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE.

Comment: Return 0 when 0x11 and 1 when 0x0

Comment: The return value 0 means FALSE in C. So you need to call the ```GetLastError()``` to get the error code. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity#return-value).

Comment: windll.kernel32.GetLastError() returns 8, ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Comment: The bug was resolved by removing `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` and `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`. Thanks to @relent95 and [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723579/call-win32-api-in-flex-to-set-window-display-affinity).

Comment: Looking for a solution to create a FramelessWindow without any issues, now.

Comment: Simple fix: add SetWindowDisplayAffinity before loading the flags.

Comment: What about answering your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I came across an issue where using the *SetWindowDisplayAffinity* function was generating error 8. I discovered that the issue was related to the following UI flags being set:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

For some reason, these flags interfere with the *SetWindowDisplayAffinity* function.

**FIX**

An obvious solution would be to remove these flags, but in my case, I wanted to keep them. After some investigation, I found that *SetWindowDisplayAffinity* needs to come before those flags to fix the issue. Here is the corrected code:

```
# SetWindowDisplayAffinity on top of the flags.
windll.user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, 11)

self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

do not forget to run as admin